Help finding the limit of an integral using the Fundamental theorem of calculus
I've been given this homework assignment:
Let $a\geq 0$ and let $g(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a, \infty)$ such that for all $x\geq a$:
$$\left|\int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt \right|\leq C$$
For some constant $C$. Let $f(x)$ be a function with a continuous derivative on interval $[a,b]$. Prove that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(nx)dx=0$$
So here is my attempt: I see a product so let's try integration by parts. let $u=f(x)$ since it's differentiable and $v'=g(nx)$ since it's integrable. So $u'=f'(x)$ and $v=\int_{a}^{x}g(nt)dt$ (is this correct?). Then we get: $$\Big(f(x)\cdot\int_{a}^{x}g(nt)dt\Big)\Big|_a^b - \int_{a}^{b}\Big(f'(x)\int_{a}^{x}g(nt)dt\Big)$$
But how on earth do I continue from here? Is there any other suggested method to solve this? Thanks!
Many thanks to the helpers!

$\int\limits_a^xg(nt),dt={1\over n}\int\limits_{na}^{nb}g(t),dt$ should help.

Did you derive this by the substituion method? And what does that give us?

Yes, $t=x/n,$ hence $dt=dx/n.$

Your proof gives the conclusion taking into account my first comment. Moreover the absolute value of the integral is bounded by  constant times $n^{-1}.$

In what you wrote, how’d you get to $nb$ on the upper bound? Shouldn't it be $nx$? Also why can we use the constant $C$ given to us, if we changed the bounds?

A misprint. Sorry

Call $G(x)=\int\limits_a^xg(t)dt$ and $k_n(x)=G(nx)$. The given conditions imply
$$
k_n(x)\le C,
$$
where $C$ is independent of $n$. Next, by the chain rule and integrating by parts,
$$
\int\limits_a^bf(x)g(nx)\,dx=\frac 1{n}\int\limits_a^bf(x)k_n'(x)\,dx=\frac 1{n}\left\{f(b)k_n(b)-f(a)k_n(a)-\int\limits_a^bf'(x)k_n(x)\,dx\right\}
$$
and, by the triangle inequality and the estimate on $k_n$,
$$
\left|\int\limits_a^bf(x)g(nx)\,dx\right|\le\frac C{n}\left\{|f(b)|+|f(a)|+\int\limits_a^b|f'(x)|dx\right\}
$$
Taking the limit $n\to\infty$ concludes the proof.

Why is it still true that $k_n(x)\leq C,$ even though there’s a $n$ next to the $x$? How can I formally explain this?

Because $k_n(x)=\int_a^{nx}g(t)dt$ and those integrals are bounded independently of the upper limit.

I mean $\int_a^{anything}g(z)dz\le C$

I see now. And can you explain the last part? Like what exactly happened to the integral left from the integration by parts.

Sure.  I realized that since we do not control the sign of $f'$ we need to proceed a bit differently (I modified the last line in the proof). It goes like this: $|\int\limits_a^bf'(x)k_n(x),dx|\le \int\limits_a^b|f'(x)||k_n(x)|,dx\le C  \int\limits_a^b|f'(x)|dx$. The latter integral is well defined and does not depend on $n$, so it does not make any difference in the limit.

Ok I understand what you did now. You basically turned all the terms with a minus to abs value so you can safely use the $C$ property, without accidentally lowering the value instead of increasing it (cause of the minus).

That is correct.

Neat, thanks a lot
